# Cannot call chatGPT-API (REST API) from javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am trying to call ChatGPT REST API from JavaScript:

**JS**:

```
const apiUrl = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions';
const apiKey = '<open-ai-key>';
const inputPrompt = options.prompt;
fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "messages": [{
            "role": "system",
            "content": "You are ChatGPT, a helpful assistant."
        }, {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Your input prompt here."
        }]
    })
}).then(response => {
    if(!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    return response.json();
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data.choices[0].message.content);
}).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: Error: HTTP error! status: 400

I have tried:

- API key is correct and hasn't expired;
- Content-Type header is set to 'application/json';
- this is the API endpoint URL suggested by ChatGPT (but could be different now?);
- no rate limits have been exceeded;
- tried changing the system and User Message order.

Comment: “ this is the API endpoint URL suggested by chatGPT” — are you reading their API documentation (including a link would make it easier to help you) or asking the chatbot (which is designed to generate reasonable sounding sentences not facts)

Comment: @Quentin 

I have been using Open AI's API REFERENCE:
https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/making-requests

I have also been in conversation with the chatbot. It only mentions the steps that I listed above for attempting to resolve the issue. Then says "contact openai support" which is nothing but FAQ articles, although I did join their Discord group.

Comment: @Yogi yes that’s a good catch. I actually noticed the same, and implemented the model field within the body of the request, but now get a “rate limit exceeded” error, which makes no sense since I got this error when only calling the endpoint once.

Comment: @yogi Thank you, it was indeed related to an issue with an account setting. Working now.

Answer (score 1):

OpenAI Chat Completions require a [model](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create#chat-create-model) in the request body. It can be easily fixed by adding one line of code:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages": [{
        "role": "system",
        "content": "You are ChatGPT, a helpful assistant."
    }, {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "Your input prompt here."
    }]
})
```

I recommend using the [OpenAI npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai) to simplify usage and prevent mistakes like this in the future.